# Oracle Apex Error while updating interactive grid report values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating an application in Oracle Apex which using a table with 63 columns where I updated the values. While saving I got this error:

> ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here' while executing a DML command. This error can occur if a column is based on an aggregation or SQL expression.

[image: image of error message above]

Comment: You need to provide the code you have written for this and some more info. Otherwise, no one can guess it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at IG's query. I presume that some of columns don't belong to the table IG is based on. All those columns are referred to as "virtual columns" and should not be part of DML executed by automatic row processing.

What to do? Navigate to those columns' properties and set their "**Query only**" property to "Yes".